# How do I populate a Lightning:combobox with content from a map?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, controller, map, javascript-controller

I've generated a map in my apex controller which I would like to use to populate a combobox. Simplified code below:

Component:

```
<aura:component controller="myController" implements="force:lightningQuickAction,force:hasRecordId" >
    <aura:attribute name="quarters" type="Map" default="[]"/>
...etc
    <lightning:combobox name="quarters" label="Quarters" placeholder="Select a Fiscal Quarter" options="{!v.quarters}" onchange="{!c.handleChange}"/>
```

Controller - how do I populate the attribute on the component to fill the combobox? I know what I have isn't correct, but would appreciate help in how to do this please? The apex controller populates a map with the quarter names and dates. I would like to display the quarter name in the combobox and pick up the date when one is selected.

```
var quartermap = response.getReturnValue().mapQuarters;
var quarters = [];
if(quartermap.length > 0){
    for (var i = 0; i < quartermap.length; i++){
        var item = {
            "label": quarterOption[0].key,
            "value": quarterOption[0].value,
        };
        quarters.push(item);                            
    }
}
component.set("v.quarters", quarters);
```

Answer (score 2):

You are doing fine. You need to modify the code in Controller. To assign the label and value.

```
var quartermap = response.getReturnValue().mapQuarters;
var quarters = [];
if(quartermap.length > 0){
   for (for key in quartermap){
     var item = {
        label: key,
        value: quarterOption[key]
    };
    quarters.push(item);                            
  }
}
component.set("v.quarters", quarters);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  @track quartermap =[];
  @track quarters = [];

  if(this.quartermap.length>0)
   {
        for(let i in this.quartermap){
           this.quarters = [...this.quartermap ,{value: this.quartermap[i].Id.toString(), label: this.quartermap[i].Name.toString()} ];
            
   }
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: On SFSE the *why* (explanation) is often as or more important than the *how* (code) in an answer. (Especially when you are adding an answer to a nearly 3-year-old question.) Please [edit](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/posts/369769/edit) your answer to add some explanation on how it differs from and possibly improves on the other answer.